# Moving objects with random orientation in Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

First of all let me be clear I dont know anything about Maya. A guy at the office wants to spawn random particles in a field. Then he gives them a random rotation vector so that they look in random locations. He wants to attached people to the particles and move them like that. The question is how to move the particles in the direction of the rotation vector they have been assigned on creation. If someone here knows Python or MEL i would greatly appreciate the help.

**Edit:**

This is the code that orients the particles in a random way. This is simply what I got from the Maya guy.

```
nParticleShape1.rotationPP=<<0,rand(360),0>>; 
nParticleShape1.parentU=rand(0,1); 
nParticleShape1.parentV=rand(0,1);
nParticleShape1.goalU=nParticleShape1.parentU;  
nParticleShape1.goalV=nParticleShape1.parentV;
```

Comment: Maya-related questions are so _rare_ I'm always on the look-out for them. See, normally you'd be in luck because I know Maya, Mel _and_ Python. But, unfortunately, I haven't experimented much with particles. If no one's given this a shot by Monday, I _might_ take a stab.

Comment: I just need something like a MoveForward function. I program in C# but I have no idea how to make that in MEL and to be honest I dont want to learn since its not even my job. The script that randomly rotates the particles is done all I need is something to move the in the direction they were rotated

Comment: Can you share the code that s been written so far.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of his outliner to show how he organizes his particles? I'll try writing something in python then.

Comment: You should also check and find out if your co-worker knows how to get the particle motion desired or not -- gluing objects to the particles is one problem, animating the particles is another ....